# overriding UINavigationBar drawRect function doesnt work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a simple app with a nav bar controller and I would like to change its navigation bar while overriding the drawRect function. I read in many places here that all I need to do is just to paste the code below above my appDelegate. Sadly, it doesnt seem to do anything for me. I tried as a start to just have the color of the nav bar changed, before i try to add an image to it, but again, nothing happens. What am i missing here

I tired to insert this code above the AppDelegate:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
 UIColor *color = [UIColor redColor];
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColor(context, CGColorGetComponents( [color CGColor]));
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
  }
 @end
```

And with the background image:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
// Drawing code 
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"13.png"];
[img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.frame.size.height)];    
}
@end
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code declares a category on `UINavigationBar` and redefines the behaviour of its `drawRect:` method. Try to put the code snippet (second one) at the end of the `.m` file of the app delegate.

Although the first should work, another more clean option is to write the category in a separate file you will include in the app delegate.

Also make sure the picture you are loading exists in the app bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - solution found! This doesnt seem to work on the iPhone 5.0 simulator!

Comment: Try to look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657465/uinavigationbars-drawrect-is-not-called-in-ios-5-0