# Customize NavigationBar in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, uinavigationbar, ios5

In `iOs4` i created a  custom navigation bar using this snippet

```
#import "UINavigationBar+CustomImage.h"


@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"] retain];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.frame.size.width , self.frame.size.height)];
    [image release];
    }
@end
```

and it is well for ios4 in my app. Now I want to run this in `iOs5` and the problem is that the custom navigation bar doesn't appear the way I want.

Can any one help me to create a custom navigation bar for `iOs5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same problem is mentioned here: [UINavigationBar's drawRect is not called in iOS 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657465/uinavigationbars-drawrect-is-not-called-in-ios-5-0). Please check this may help you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the appearance proxy.  But, make sure to check if respondsToSelector for iOS4.  Leave your current method in place for iOS4 and it will work on both.

```
// not supported on iOS4
UINavigationBar *navBar = [purchaseNavController navigationBar];
if ([navBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)])
{
    // set globablly for all UINavBars
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"brnlthr_nav.jpg"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    // could optionally set for just this navBar
    //[navBar setBackgroundImage:...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put the following code in the application delegate and it will work fine, Even in ios5
I put it in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions


// Create image for navigation background - portrait

UIImage *NavigationPortraitBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavigationPortraitBackground"] 
                                             resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

// Create image for navigation background - landscape

UIImage *NavigationLandscapeBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavigationLandscapeBackground"] 
                                          resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];


// Set the background image all UINavigationBars

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:NavigationPortraitBackground 
                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:NavigationLandscapeBackground 
                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
```

Answer (score 0):

*Check the iOS version and set the navigation bar image*

**if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]floatValue]  <5.0){ }
    else{

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Sample.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }**