# UINavigationBar with custom background and title font for iOS4 and iOS5

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

What is the best way to implement a UINavigationBar that has a custom background and a custom title font, for both iOS4 and iOS5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `drawRect` in a custom `UINavigationBar` class:

```
- (void)drawRect {
    [super drawRect];

    [self addSubview:customNavigationBackgroundView];
}
```

Then, in the class that uses this navigation bar, run `navigationBar.titleView = desiredTitleLabel`.  To customize the font of this label, try `desiredTitleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"name" size:22.0]`.

You can then customize the text color, shadow, etc. of the shadow.

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 5.x, you can use UINavigationBar's setTitleTextAttributes for setting the font, color, offset, and shadow color of the title.

In iOS 4.x, it is not a bad idea to set a UILabel as the titleView property of the navigationBar.

Answer (score 3):

for background, just see here
[UINavigationBar (CustomBackground)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8970451/501764)

and for font you can use a text label to set font in iOS4 and in iOS5 you can do it like this

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f] forKey:UITextAttributeFont];
```