# Customize navigation bar with title view

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am trying to add a custom view in the center of a navigation bar and I am using the following code to test it:

```
UIView * testView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[testView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
testView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 35);
[self.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView addSubview:testView];
```

I am setting this up in the viewDidLoad method of my view controller but when i run my program 
nothing seems to change in my navigation bar.

Could you help me with this?

Comment: Check out this post...


[custon uinavigationbars supportable for iOS4 and iOS5][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657465/uinavigationbars-drawrect-is-not-called-in-ios-5-0


Hope it helps.. :)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This works. Give frame at the time of initialisation

```
UIView *iv = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,32,32)];
[iv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
self.navigationItem.titleView = iv;
```

Comment: Yes that was exactly it! Thanks a lot! can i ask you why i can't access to the navigation item using: "self.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView" is it wrong to access the navigation item from the navigation controller. Thanks a lot @virata

Comment: @JulianOsorio It's not the problem about `self.navigationItem.titleView` and `self.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView`, it's the different between `addSubview` and `setTitleView`. :)

Comment: u r welcome Julian,navigationItem is your class's own property. Don't try to access it through navigationController's property.

Comment: Excellent I get it now! Thanks to you two.

Comment: Weird, it doesn't work on iOS 7.. I added a searchBar.. and I get complaints about autolayout stuffs..

Answer (score 34):

If you want to just customize the title for one view controller you can use

```
UILabel *lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc] init];
lblTitle.text = @"Diga-nos o motivo";
lblTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lblTitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:77.0/255.0 green:77.0/255.0 blue:77.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
lblTitle.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
lblTitle.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
lblTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:18.0];
[lblTitle sizeToFit];

self.navigationItem.titleView = lblTitle;
```

or if you want to customize for all view controllers use

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], 
        UITextAttributeTextColor, 
        [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8], 
        UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, 
        [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)], 
        UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, 
        [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Bold" size:10.0], 
        UITextAttributeFont, 
        nil]];
```

Comment: You can favourite the question @MusiGenesis :)

Answer (score 27):

Replace

```
[self.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView addSubview:testView];
```

to

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = testView;
```

### Edit:

Note: You cannot add subviews to titleView cause it's default value is `nil`, you need to set a new view as the titleView.

Comment: But you can add a subview to `self.navigationController.navigationBar`.

Comment: @KyleClegg um.. I don't like to add subviews on navigation bar, except button items. ;)

Comment: @Kjuly agreed, I was just trying to get a `UIPageControl` in the nav bar similar to the Twitter app and that's how I was able to do it easily. Depending on how you want to customize the titleview it can be useful.

Comment: But adding titleview is not covering the full navigation bar. Looks like comes with its own default insets :-(

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3/4**

You may set i.e. `UILabel` as a `titleView`. Call it in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
private func setNavigationTitle(_ title: String) {
    navigationItem.title = nil // clear the default title
    let titleLabel = UILabel() // you don't need to specify a frame, it will be centred in the navbar
    titleLabel.font = ...
    titleLabel.textColor = ...
    titleLabel.text = title
    titleLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
    navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
    navigationTitleView = titleLabel // you may create a property if you want to manipulate the title view later
}
```

**Note** `navigationItem.title = nil`, otherwise `title` may override `titleView`.

Answer (score 1):

```
CustomLabel *titleLabel = [CustomLabel initWithLabelFrame:labelFrame textFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:[UIFont systemFontSize]] textColor:[UIColor blackColor] labelText:@"Add as" textAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter labelOnView:reference.view labelTag:62];

[self.navigationItem setTitleView:titleLabel]; // titleLabel set in navigationItem
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your answer to put the code inside a code block to make it more readable. This can be done by putting four spaces at the start of each line, or marking the code and pressing the `{}` button.

Answer (score 1):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 
@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController
@end


#import "MasterViewController.h"
@interface MasterViewController ()
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = [self titleView];
}

- (UIView *)titleView {
    CGFloat navBarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat width = 0.95 * self.view.frame.size.width;
    UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, navBarHeight)];

    UIImage *logo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"];
    UIButton *logoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    CGFloat logoY = floorf((navBarHeight - logo.size.height) / 2.0f);
    [logoButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, logoY, logo.size.width, logo.size.height)];
    [logoButton setImage:logo forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIImage *bubble = [UIImage imageNamed:@"notification-bubble-empty.png"];
    UIImageView *bubbleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bubble];

    const CGFloat Padding = 5.0f;
    CGFloat bubbleX = 
        logoButton.frame.size.width + 
        logoButton.frame.origin.x + 
        Padding;
    CGFloat bubbleY = floorf((navBarHeight - bubble.size.height) / 2.0f);
    CGRect bubbleRect = bubbleView.frame;
    bubbleRect.origin.x = bubbleX;
    bubbleRect.origin.y = bubbleY;
    bubbleView.frame = bubbleRect;

    [containerView addSubview:logoButton];
    [containerView addSubview:bubbleView];

    return containerView;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use storyboard to do this to support iPhone 6 and newer (larger) devices.

Create a container view for your custom navigation item title/subtitle etc, and drag it into the visual editor (not into the view hierarchy).

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**

```
let myImageView = UIImageView(image: <...set your image...>)

override fun viewDidLoad(){
   super.viewDidLoad()
   self.navigationItem.titleView = myImageView  //
}
```

One more alternate solution is

```
override fun viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super. viewWillAppear(animated)
   self.navigationItem.titleView = myImageView
}
```

I recommend to use, `viewDidLoad` to setup your `titleView`