# How to make a navigation bar like that of Bumble

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

In mumble's Setting page there exists this navigation bar/tab bar that allows you to switch between profile and settings. Can you please give me an idea how I can imitate that in my app?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can customize `UINavigationItem`'s `titleView` property with custom view for starters. Adding `UISegmentedControl` to that custom view could be your solution.

Comment: Thanks! UISegmentedControl is what I was looking for. Can you tell me what you mean by customizing UINavigationItem's titleView property? Is it more than removing the title and adding the segmented control at its position?

Comment: Actually it isn't like that. You may check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433016/customize-navigation-bar-with-title-view)
You may add UISegmentedControl as a subview that you are gonna add to titleView.

Answer (score 1):

The `UINavigationBar` has 3 properties called `leftBarButtonItem`, `rightBarButtonItem` and `titleView`.

Create the `leftBarButtonItem` and `rightBarButtonItem` using `[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aCustomView]`.

For the `titleView`, you can use a `UISegmentedControl`, but if you want to achieve that kind of custom look you're going to have to implement your own segmented control.

Answer (score 0):

Just built this - check it out and let me know what you think.

---

```
import UIKit

class CDSlideView: UIView {

    var leftBackView: UIView!
    var leftBackLabel: UILabel!
    var leftFrontView: UIView!
    var leftFrontLabel: UILabel!

    var rightBackView: UIView!
    var rightBackLabel: UILabel!
    var rightFrontView: UIView!
    var rightFrontLabel: UILabel!

    var foregroundView: UIView!
    var backgroundView: UIView!

    var slideGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer!

    let lightColor: UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    let darkColor: UIColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    let leftText: String = "Search"
    let rightText: String = "New"

    var viewWidth: CGFloat!
    var viewHeight: CGFloat!
    var leftOrigin: CGFloat!
    var rightOrigin: CGFloat!
    var foregroundPadding: CGFloat = 4

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // Init variables variables
        viewWidth = self.frame.size.width
        viewHeight = self.frame.size.height
        leftOrigin = foregroundPadding / 2
        rightOrigin = (viewWidth - foregroundPadding) / 2 + foregroundPadding / 2

        backgroundView = UIView()
        backgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight)
        backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = backgroundView.frame.size.height / 2
        self.addSubview(backgroundView)

        leftBackView = UIView()
        leftBackView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, backgroundView.frame.size.width / 2, backgroundView.frame.size.height)
        self.backgroundView.addSubview(leftBackView)

        leftBackLabel = UILabel()
        leftBackLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, leftBackView.frame.size.width, leftBackView.frame.size.height)
        leftBackLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13, weight: UIFontWeightSemibold)
        leftBackLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        leftBackLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByClipping
        leftBackLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        self.leftBackView.addSubview(leftBackLabel)

        rightBackView = UIView()
        rightBackView.frame = CGRectMake(backgroundView.frame.size.width / 2, 0, backgroundView.frame.size.width / 2, backgroundView.frame.size.height)
        self.backgroundView.addSubview(rightBackView)

        rightBackLabel = UILabel()
        rightBackLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, rightBackView.frame.size.width, rightBackView.frame.size.height)
        rightBackLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13, weight: UIFontWeightSemibold)
        rightBackLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        rightBackLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByClipping
        rightBackLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        self.rightBackView.addSubview(rightBackLabel)

        foregroundView = UIView()
        foregroundView.frame = CGRectMake(foregroundPadding / 2, foregroundPadding / 2, (backgroundView.frame.size.width - foregroundPadding) / 2, backgroundView.frame.size.height - foregroundPadding)
        foregroundView.clipsToBounds = true
        foregroundView.layer.cornerRadius = (foregroundView.frame.size.height - foregroundPadding / 2) / 2
        self.addSubview(foregroundView)

        slideGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CDSlideView.slideAction))
        self.foregroundView.addGestureRecognizer(slideGesture)

        leftFrontView = UIView()
        leftFrontView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, backgroundView.frame.size.width / 2, backgroundView.frame.size.height)
        self.foregroundView.addSubview(leftFrontView)

        leftFrontLabel = UILabel()
        leftFrontLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13, weight: UIFontWeightSemibold)
        leftFrontLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        leftFrontLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        leftFrontLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByClipping
        leftFrontLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        self.leftFrontView.addSubview(leftFrontLabel)

        let leftFrontLabelLeadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: leftFrontLabel, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: self.backgroundView.frame.origin.x)
        self.addConstraint(leftFrontLabelLeadingConstraint)

        let leftFrontLabelTopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: leftFrontLabel, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: self.backgroundView.frame.origin.y)
        self.addConstraint(leftFrontLabelTopConstraint)

        let leftFrontLabelWidthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: leftFrontLabel, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: leftFrontView.frame.size.width)
        self.addConstraint(leftFrontLabelWidthConstraint)

        let leftFrontLabelHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: leftFrontLabel, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: leftFrontView.frame.size.height)
        self.addConstraint(leftFrontLabelHeightConstraint)

        rightFrontView = UIView()
        rightFrontView.frame = CGRectMake(backgroundView.frame.size.width / 2, 0, backgroundView.frame.size.width / 2, backgroundView.frame.size.height)
        self.foregroundView.addSubview(rightFrontView)

        rightFrontLabel = UILabel()
        rightFrontLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13, weight: UIFontWeightSemibold)
        rightFrontLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        rightFrontLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        rightFrontLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByClipping
        rightFrontLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        self.rightFrontView.addSubview(rightFrontLabel)

        let rightFrontLabelTrailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: rightFrontLabel, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: self.backgroundView.frame.origin.x)
        self.addConstraint(rightFrontLabelTrailingConstraint)

        let rightFrontLabelTopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: rightFrontLabel, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: self.backgroundView.frame.origin.y)
        self.addConstraint(rightFrontLabelTopConstraint)

        let rightFrontLabelWidthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: rightFrontLabel, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: rightFrontView.frame.size.width)
        self.addConstraint(rightFrontLabelWidthConstraint)

        let rightFrontLabelHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: rightFrontLabel, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: rightFrontView.frame.size.height)
        self.addConstraint(rightFrontLabelHeightConstraint)

        let leftTapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CDSlideView.leftTap(_:)))
        self.leftBackView.addGestureRecognizer(leftTapGesture)

        let rightTapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CDSlideView.rightTap(_:)))
        self.rightBackView.addGestureRecognizer(rightTapGesture)

        self.setLabelText(leftText, rightText: rightText)
        self.setLightColor(lightColor)
        self.setDarkColor(darkColor)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // MARK: Setup
    func setLightColor(lightColor: UIColor) {
        let lightColor = lightColor
        self.foregroundView.backgroundColor = lightColor
        self.leftBackLabel.textColor = lightColor
        self.rightBackLabel.textColor = lightColor
    }

    func setDarkColor(darkColor: UIColor) {
        let darkColor = darkColor
        self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = darkColor
        self.leftFrontLabel.textColor = darkColor
        self.rightFrontLabel.textColor = darkColor
    }

    func setLabelText(leftText: String, rightText: String) {
        self.leftFrontLabel.text = leftText
        self.leftBackLabel.text = leftText
        self.rightFrontLabel.text = rightText
        self.rightBackLabel.text = rightText
    }

    // MARK: Actions
    func slideAction(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == .Began || sender.state == .Changed {
            let translation = sender.translationInView(self)
            // note: 'view' is optional and need to be unwrapped

            // Figure out where the user is trying to drag
            var newCenter: CGPoint = CGPointMake(sender.view!.center.x + translation.x, sender.view!.center.y)

            // Limit the bounds & update the center
            newCenter.x = max(self.frame.size.width * 0.25 + foregroundPadding / 2, newCenter.x)
            newCenter.x = min(self.frame.size.width * 0.75 - foregroundPadding / 2, newCenter.x)

            // Set new center
            sender.view!.center = newCenter
            sender.setTranslation(CGPointMake(0,0), inView: self)
        } else if sender.state == .Ended {
            let senderVCX = sender.view?.center.x

            // Snap to side
            if senderVCX <= viewWidth / 2 {
                print("called left")
                sender.view?.frame.origin.x = self.leftOrigin
            } else {
                print("called right")
                sender.view?.frame.origin.x = self.rightOrigin
            }
        }
    }

    func leftTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.05) {
            self.foregroundView.frame.origin.x = self.leftOrigin
        }
    }

    func rightTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.05) {
            self.foregroundView.frame.origin.x = self.rightOrigin
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a tremendous amount of undocumented code. I'm not going to claim to know Swift. But the idea of reading through all of this in the hope of finding a relevant solution makes my head spin.