# Add UICollectionView to NavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to add a UICollectionView as a SubView to my NavigationBar.

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.hotspotCollectionView];
```

It seems to work properly but covers the back button, see the screenshot attached. Is there anyway to indent the collectionView so that the back button is properly visible? Also is there a way to increase the height of the navigationbar so I can use bigger thumbnail pictures in my CollectionView?

I'm using XCode 7 and iOS9.

[image: CollectionView in NavigationBar]

Comment: Did you try adding collectionview into navigationItem's titleView as described in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433016/customize-navigation-bar-with-title-view)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to achieve this simple example

[image: screenshot]

[image]
by using a subclass of UINavigationBar and setting a collection view to the view controller's navigationItem.titleView

---

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NavigationBar : UINavigationBar

@end
```

---

```
#import "NavigationBar.h"

@implementation NavigationBar

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size
{
    return CGSizeMake(self.superview.bounds.size.width, 80);
}

-(void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    CGRect f = frame;
    f.size.height = 80;
    [super setFrame:f];
}

@end
```

---

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

---

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CollectionViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>
@property (nonatomic, weak) UICollectionView *collectionView;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

    UICollectionView *collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 80) collectionViewLayout:layout];
    collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = collectionView;
    [collectionView registerClass:[CollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    collectionView.delegate = self;
    collectionView.dataSource = self;
}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    return cell;
}
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(50, 50);
}

@end
```

---

I set the custom NavigationBar in the Interface Builder

[image: screenshot]

---

*Disclaimer 1:* I cannot promise that this is a future proof solution or will work in any case. I didn't test it with things like auto layout or rotation.

*Disclaimer 2:* I personally would implement any datasource/delegate independently from the view controller. For tableViews and collection views I use my self grown [OFAPopulator](http://vikingosegundo.github.io/ofapopulator/).

---

Here is a example code: gitlab.com/vikingosegundo/collectionview-in-navigationbar/tree/… there are still some UI quirks in it. But probably that was to be expected. I guess Apple just did not consider us changing the height. Actually I never saw an app with a different height for it's nav bar. But the code answers your question. Give it more love and it may be useful for you.

Comment: Wouldn't that make all NavigationBars look that way? Also, I haven't tried out your approach but this would still cover the Back button for example.

Comment: no, won't cover the back button. see new screenshot.

Comment: *Wouldn't that make all NavigationBars look that way?* only where you use the custom class. And you could add a method to switch between normal style and custom.

Comment: Well I can only set the navigationBar class in the root NavigationViewController, or am I wrong?

Comment: You can use different navigation controller.

Comment: awesome, thank you so much for your help :) You put quite some afford into it!

Comment: You got me curious if it was possible. Never tried it before.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best decision in this situation is to use custom `UIView` subclass that mimics `UINavigationBar`. And `setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO` to corresponding `UINavigationController`.

Comment: If you do this and push a view to your navigation controller won't your UIView disappear?