# Scrollview in navigation

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

Guys I want to make this screen for my App. I don't know how to make this scrollview into navigation using programmatically. please I want to make this scrollview programmatically similar design.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a collectionview you can acheive this by adding a collectionview in NavigationBar

```
weak var collectionView: UICollectionView?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let navigationitem = UINavigationItem(title: "")    //creates a new item with no title
    navigationitem.titleView = collectionView //your collectionview here to display as a view instead of the title that is usually there
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.items = [navigationitem] //adds the navigation item to the navigationbar
}
```

For more assistance check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40964118/how-to-put-a-collection-view-in-the-navigation-bar-like-in-imessage-group-chats)