# Add UICollectionView with a UILabel and UIImageView in UINavigation item title view

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem, titleview

I want to add UICollectionView with a UILabel and a button to the title view of navigation item. Please refer  [image: here "i" is button with "4" count of users with collection of users]

I have taken back icon as leftBarButtonItem and attachment and delete icon as rightBarButtonItem. I have created custom view for title view looks same as shown in UI. While adding custom view to title view i am unable to scroll the UICollectionView even i don't get touch event for "i" button.

Comment: I think this is perfect to you....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36377942/add-uicollectionview-to-navigationbar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add UICollectionView to NavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36377942/add-uicollectionview-to-navigationbar)

Comment: I have added the collection view in title view but i an unable to scroll and get touch event for button.