# Cut the view using drawRect method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am new to iPhone programming. I have to use the `drawRect` method to cut the view in an iPhone app. I implemented the `drawRect` method but it is not be called properly. Can anyone suggest how to resolve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "cutting the view"? Also, please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Refer this link..i will definitely help you][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657465/uinavigationbars-drawrect-is-not-called-in-ios-5-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please double check have you subclassed uiview or uiviewcontroller,because this is a common mistake.

Comment: Thank you.I have taken UIViewController,but at that time it was not accessed.After that i have taken subclass of UIView,In that class i used drawRect method...

Comment: It is not working. I have written code in the subclass of UIView                                                             - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
   UIRectFill( rect );
   CGRect gapArea = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x,rect.origin.y,rect.size.width,rect.size.height);
   CGRect rectTofill = CGRectIntersection(gapArea, rect );
   [[UIColor clearColor] setFill];
   
   UIRectFill( rectTofill );
}

Comment: and In touchesBegin method is in mainview controller...                                                            -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];;
//    viewScreen.hidden=YES;
  CGPoint currentPosition = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
   CGRect rectValue=CGRectMake(currentPosition.x,currentPosition.y, 50,50);
   NewView *newInstance=[[NewView alloc]init];
   [newInstance drawRect:rectValue];
   [newInstance release];
}
 So please suggest me how to call that drawRect method.